# SEDE incorrectly converts linked fields to CSV

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

SEDE gives incorrect CSV for linked fields.  The first 9 lines from the [query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/10116/) where I noticed it:

```
 User Link,,Reputation
 {
   "title": "miguel.de.icaza",
   "id": 16929
 },9.8,8374
 {
   "title": "Joel Spolsky",
   "id": 4
 },9.054545,8175
```

And it also affects post links:

> select id as [Post Link], owneruserid as [User Link] from posts where id=42;​​​​

```
Post Link,User Link
{
  "title": "Best way to allow plugins for a PHP application",
  "id": 42
},{
  "title": "Wally Lawless",
  "id": 37
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this now and got:

```
User Link,,Reputation
"{
  ""title"": ""John Resig"",
  ""id"": 6524
}","59.6","5807"
"{
  ""title"": ""Reto Meier"",
  ""id"": 822
}","12.140845","9574"
```

(Note the additional quoting and escaping.)

The second field does not have a column name because it isn't aliased in the source query.

Now, about the JSON-style column results -- is this supposed to be on a single line? This doesn't technically break CSV (or does it?), but it's much harder to process after the fact. Would people prefer it to be on a single line? Please let me know in comments.

I.e.,

```
User Link,,Reputation
"{""title"": ""John Resig"",""id"": 6524}","59.6","5807"
"{""title"": ""Reto Meier"",""id"": 822}","12.140845","9574"
```

Comment: Since I don't see anyone commenting, I'm going to assume the way it is now is sufficient. If you want it changed, file a feature request. :)